# UserControl enum DependencyProperty not binding

Tags: wpf, user-controls, enums, dependency-properties

I created a UserControl that contains 3 DependencyProperties. Two are working fine, but there is one that gives me a real headache.
I have an enum (outside the UserControl class but same namespace):

```
public enum RecordingType
{
    NoRecording,
    ContinuesRecording,
    EventRecording
}
```

I created a DependencyProperty for it as follows:

```
public static DependencyProperty SelectedRecordingTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedRecordingType", typeof(RecordingType), typeof(SchedulerControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((RecordingType)RecordingType.NoRecording, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public RecordingType SelectedRecordingType
    {
        get
        {
            return (RecordingType)GetValue(SelectedRecordingTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedRecordingTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

and I'm using it in XAML like this:

```
<userControls:SchedulerControl
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="3"
                        SelectedRecordingType="{Binding CurrentRecordingType,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
                        FullRecordingSchedule="{Binding MondayFullRecordingSchedule,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        SelectedRecordingTime="{Binding MondaySelectedRecordingTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

There are two more DependencyProperties that work just fine (I get to their get and set methods inside the UserControl), but this one is just a no-go. I created DPs before and I'm doing everything the same. I also made sure the binding in my VM is ok and the getter and setter are being called correctly.

Any help would be great!

Also I checked that I my VM. The binding does execute.

Comment: The getter and setter methods are usually bypassed by XAML-generated code. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.110).aspx#implications) for an explanation. The fact that they aren't called is not an indication that the binding doesn't work. You should have a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events).

Answer (score 1):

Let me show an other solution for `UserControl` (UC from now) with a `ComboBox` and `Enum` bindings.
Also a common problem, when you can bind the enum, but you can't get the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` from the UC. This solution will also provide the `SelectedItem`.

For example, I have an `ExampleUC : UserControl` UC class, which is able to accept an enum, and to provide the `SelectedItem`. It will do it using properties (attributes in .xaml).
I also have an enum, called `ExampleEnum`, and the `Window`, which creates a new instance of `ExampleUC` and setting that's properties/attributes.

In the ExampleUC.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestNamespace.View.ExampleUC"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:TestNamespace.View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:markup="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={markup:Type view:ExampleUC}}}">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EnumTypeArray}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see, the `DataContext` of the UC has been set to it's ancestor's DataContext, which means it can receive the wanted parameters (you can find more explanations about DataContext inheritance and visual tree, just make some researches about them).

The binded properties (EnumTypeArray and SelectedItem) are DependencyProperties in the ExampleUC.xaml.cs file:

```
public Array EnumTypeArray
{
    get { return (Array)GetValue(EnumTypeArrayProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EnumTypeArrayProperty, value); }
}

public object SelectedItem
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty EnumTypeArrayProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("EnumTypeArray", typeof(Array), typeof(ExampleUC), new PropertyMetadata(new string[0]));

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(ExampleUC), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

To create new `DependencyProperty` you can use the `propdp` code snippet. (Write it and press TAB by default). These properties will be shown as attributes in the .xaml editor, when you create and edit the instances of ExampleUC.

At this stage you have a UC, which can accept an enum, and return the `SelectedItem`.

The enum somewhere:

```
public enum ExampleEnum
{
    Example1,
    Example2
}
```

The `Window`, which uses the ExampleUC:

You have to add a new resource to the Window's resources, which will be an `ObjectDataProvider` in order to be able to use your enum as `ItemsSource`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyEnumName" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:ExampleEnum"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

Please note that, the `local` namespace prefix has been defined earlier at the namespaces' section, which is the namespace of `ExampleEnum`, for example:

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNamespace.Data"`

To use `ExampleUC`, in a `Grid` or `Panel`, use the following:

```
<views:ExampleUC EnumTypeArray="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyEnumName}}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

To set the `Mode` to `TwoWay` is necessary to be able to `get` and `set` the property.
Please note that, you might have to define the `views` namespace at the namespaces' section, if Visual Studio wouldn't do it for you.

As you can see, the previously defined DependencyProperties are showing up as attributes. The `EnumTypeArray` is responsible to fill the ComboBox's items, and the `SelectedItem` has been binded to MyProperty, which is a property in the model class, such as:

```
public ExampleEnum MyProperty{
    get{ return _myProperty;}
    set{
        _myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}
```

This example only shows how to use enums through UCs. Since this UC has only a single component (a `ComboBox`), it's useless in practice. If you decorate it with a `Label` or others, it would do the job.

Hope it helps.